# Django Webpack Loader setting does not render images

Tags: django, webpack

I am using `Django` `webpack loader` to render `VueJs` files. I have two similar applications and I can view the images in one application but other does not work. This is how I configure my `Vue Webpack`:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

    module.exports = {
        publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
        outputDir: './dist/',

        chainWebpack: config => {

            config.module.rules.delete('eslint');

            config.optimization
                .splitChunks(false)

            config.module
              .rule('vue')
              .use('vue-loader')
              .loader('vue-loader')
              .tap(options => {
                options.transformAssetUrls = {
                  img: 'src',
                  image: 'xlink:href',
                  'b-img': 'src',
                  'b-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
                  'b-card': 'img-src',
                  'b-card-img': 'src',
                  'b-card-img-lazy': ['src', 'blank-src'],
                  'b-carousel-slide': 'img-src',
                  'b-embed': 'src'
                }

                return options
              })

            config
                .plugin('BundleTracker')
                .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: '../frontend/webpack-stats.json'}])

            config.resolve.alias
                .set('__STATIC__', 'static')

            config.devServer
                .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
                .host('0.0.0.0')
                .port(8080)
                .hotOnly(true)
                .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
                .https(false)
                .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
                }
            };
```

These are my `Django` settings:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/bundles/',  # must end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have been struggling for two days. I can get the `image url` as text in the template, meanwhile `images` are not rendered. Anyone has a clue ?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: yes I have found a solution.  check my own answer

Comment: oh, thank you. waiting for your answer!

Comment: I have added my code, could you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering `Vue` app inside  `Django` templates, you need to edit `urls.py` for media files as below:

```
urlpatterns +=[
...
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }),
...
]
```

Comment: I get the idea, but didn't understand what is `serve` stands for. Actually, could you please check out the my question for? I showing my `urls.py` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182305/loading-media-root-files-with-django-webpack-loader