# Loading MEDIA_ROOT files with Django Webpack Loader

Tags: django, django-webpack-loader

After I setup a `vue` frontend with a `django webpack loader`, the media files are not rendering.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)


WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    "DEFAULT": {
        "BUNDLE_DIR_NAME": "dist/",
        "STATS_FILE": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend", "webpack-stats.json"),
    }
}
```

And **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include("companies.routes.urls")),
    path('api/v2/', include("projects.routes.urls")),

    path('accounts/register/', RegistrationView.as_view(
        form_class=CompanyUserForm,
        success_url="/",
    ), name="django_registration_register"),

    path('accounts/', include("django_registration.backends.one_step.urls")),
    path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('api-auth/', include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path('api/rest_auth/', include("rest_auth.urls")),
    path('api/rest_auth/django_registration/', include("rest_auth.registration.urls")),

    re_path(r'^.*$', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")
]

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }),
]

# adding the media root path.
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But when I browse the media file url, image isn't rendering. The issue lies inside **urlpatterns** at this line `re_path(r'^.*$', IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point")` when I comment out this part. I can see the image. But i need the `re_path` for the frontend view. How should fix this issue?

Comment: hello again, you have to add my answer and " from django.views.static import serve  "

Comment: `django-webpack-loader` is no longer maintained. I've been working on a replacement for it that is starting to gain traction and I def recommend trying it out: https://github.com/shonin/django-manifest-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to serve your media files add this to your `urls.py`

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    }),
]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and I did exact the same thing but, still same problem. image url text is displays, but image is not rendering. because **media path** is still not looking the backend's media file. looking frontend' file. Also update the `urls.py`  changes in question.

Comment: okay, problem solved. I gave the frontend's `re_path()` after the media `re_path()` not before. Thank you!!